# In lightning-datatable, is there a way to get focus?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning-datatable, and I'd like to use keyboard shortcuts for my actions -- but to do that I'll need to be able to determine the row that is currently in focus. I can't find documentation on that.

Any ideas?

I don't have any code written for it yet. Basically, I would add a listener to pick up the keycode, then if it's one of the active keys, I'd pull the row data from the row that is currently in focus. Something like this?

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.template.addEventListener('keyup', this.shortcuts.bind(this));
}

// KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS
shortcuts(event){
    const keycode = event.keyCode;
    if(keycode === 79){
        this.selectedRowData = [datatableName.focus.row]
        this.confirmOptOut = true;       
    }
}
```

Note the section in brackets -- that's what I'm searching for. Is there something like component.find('dataTableName').focus.row?

Comment: can you add code snippte?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get a data attribute value on the row (or any element that triggers an event) -- perhaps this can help:

I have a table row in my html as:

```
<template for:each={cases} for:item="c" for:index="idx">
    <tr key={c.Id} data-id={c.Id} data-rowidx={idx} onclick={handleSelectRow}>
    ...
```

then, in the handler, I can get the "rowidx" or the "id" value using:

```
event.currentTarget.dataset.id
event.currentTarget.dataset.rowidx
```

Comment: thanks. I'll need to grab the row id everytime there's a change in focus on the lightning-datatable -- but I don't see an onfocus event for datatable. In my example, the event is the keyup, so there is no target available.

Comment: Table elements (table/tr/td, etc) don't get focus - I don't believe they can be the target of keyboard focus.  Perhaps you are looking to capture keypress on the "document" - and you'd have to track "focus" (such as highlighting a row?) by tracking the id/order/etc in code.  However, in my experience, manipulating the DOM (using the "template" in lightning web components) has been troublesome.

Comment: PS: I ended up creating my own table -- using [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) formatting -- instead of using lightning-datatable, as I couldn't populate the cell contents the way I wanted using datatable.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm heavily invested in the datatable at this point, using just about all its built-in options. Guess I'll just have to do with that feature...